# Импорт больших данных из SQL в Neo4j

Tags: python, sql, neo4j

Имеется сервер *SQL* и сервер *Neo4j*.
В настоящий момент некоторый сценарий делает запросы в сервер *SQL*, получая данные в виде JSON. Далее полученные данные (коих очень много) бьются на пакеты и кладутся в *RabbitMQ*. С другой стороны самописный демон получает эти данные, сериализует и кладёт в *Neo4j*.
Импорт всех данных занимает около 5 часов. Сценарий загрузки запускается в час ночи. Перед началом загрузки данных данные в *Neo4j* полностью удаляются, что так же занимает очень много времени.
Как мне кажется, данный подход совершенно не продуктивный и вероятно есть решения куда лучше.
Однако другого решения на просторах интернета я не нашёл.
Прошу, подскажите

Comment: *Имеется сервер SQL* Укажите конкретную СУБД и её точную версию.

Comment: Например можно в БД сделать триггера, которые будут писать в отдельную таблицу/таблицы все изменения происходящие в данных и потом проводить в neo4j только изменения. Или не гонять все данные через MQ, а работать единым скриптом, который вычитает данные и посмотрит не изменились ли они по сравнению с тем что в neo